# jQuery scroll remove function after one use

Tags: jquery, unbind

I have a masthead that,on page load sits at the bottom of the viewport. On hover it scrolls to the top.

```
   $('.home #masthead').hover(function(){
    $("body").scrollTo($(this), 1000);
});
```

What I'd like to do is only allow this behaviour once as it causes unexpected effects as the user mouses and scrolls the page.

How to I unbind this function after it is used once?

Edit: I should probably explain the only reason I need this functionality is that there's a dropdown menu within `#masthead` cropped  by the viewport base and I think it's more elegant if I move the masthead to the top when the user is interested. It may, however, been bad UX in either case. Although it does reveal the next section rather nicely (and it happens before the user has time to get to the menu)

Comment: X/Y problem. What are the unexpected effects? Please post a [mcve] and explain what you want to happen and what happens

Comment: Did you try [`off()`](https://api.jquery.com/off/) - `$("..").on("hover", funciton() { $("..").off("hover"); $("body")...`.   Or just `.one()` which does the same.

Comment: The issue is that when the user scrolls back up the page every time they hit the `#masthead` it scrolls back up. I don't need the `off('hover')` because it's a one shot.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a global variable flag like:

```
var hasUsed = false
if(hasUsed === false){
  $('.home #masthead').hover(function(){
    hasUsed = true
    $("body").scrollTo($(this), 1000);
  });
}
```

Comment: The answer was very complete and helpful

Answer (score 1):

One option is that you could remove the #masthead class when the scrolling is done, if the #masthead is necessary for other purposes then you could add another class and remove that instead.

Comment: The element will still be cached in the jQuery object so the event listener won't be removed.

Comment: @Shikkediel Now I tried it I see what you mean! The class is irrelevant once the event listener is attached to that object in the DOM so I still need a test `hasClass`

Comment: but the best way would be to remove the event alltogether

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Renato Niola's answer with @Shikkedial's observation, we get

```
 $('.home #masthead.virgin').hover(function(){
      if ($(this).hasClass('virgin')) {
          $("body").scrollTo($(this), 1000);
          $(this).removeClass('virgin');
      }
});
```